# System.currentTimeMillis does not work properly in Scala

Tags: scala

I've noticed that `currentTimeMillis` method works incorrectly. Even if the app calculates a factorial in a `30` seconds, the difference is always `3`.

```
object Main extends App {

  def factorial(n: BigInt) = {
    val start = currentTimeMillis()
    @tailrec
    def rec(acc: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = if (n <= 1) acc else rec(n * acc, n - 1)

    val fac: BigInt = rec(1, n)
    val end = currentTimeMillis()

    ((end - start) / 1000, fac)
  }

  val res = factorial(100000)
  println(s"Get ${res._2} \n in ${res._1} seconds")

}
```

What is wrong in my code? Why does it return a wrong result?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Would you mind sharing how you executed your code? in any IDE or `scalac` in command line or ...? The 30 seconds you counted might include the compiling time and it take only 3 seconds to run the code.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code. For me here, output seems correct:

```
import java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Main extends App {
  def factorial(n: BigInt) = {
    val start = currentTimeMillis()
    @tailrec
    def rec(acc: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = if (n <= 1) acc else rec(n * acc, n - 1)

    val fac: BigInt = rec(1, n)
    val end = currentTimeMillis()

    ((end - start) / 1000, fac)
  }

  def printTimeForFactorial(n: BigInt) = {
    val res = factorial(n)
    println(s"Factorial of ${n} took ${res._1} seconds")
  }

  printTimeForFactorial(1)
  printTimeForFactorial(1000)
  printTimeForFactorial(10000)
  printTimeForFactorial(50000)
  printTimeForFactorial(100000)
  printTimeForFactorial(110000)
  printTimeForFactorial(120000)
}
```

Prints

```
Factorial of 1 took 0 seconds
Factorial of 1000 took 0 seconds
Factorial of 10000 took 0 seconds
Factorial of 50000 took 1 seconds
Factorial of 100000 took 5 seconds
Factorial of 110000 took 6 seconds
Factorial of 120000 took 7 seconds
```